# Is it possible to remove digits from an integer?

Tags: c

Is it possible to remove a digit from an integer?
For example if I want to remove all 
even digits from 123658 and be left with
135 how could I do that?

This is for an assignment, I can't use arrays, character variables
or Math.h functions.

Here is the code I have written so far

```
uint32_t phaseInt(uint32_t N, enum ProcessChoice Choice) {

   uint32_t phaseInt = 0;
   uint32_t tempVar = N;

   if (tempVar == 0){
    phaseInt = 0;
   }
   if (tempVar != 0 && Choice == Even){
    while(tempVar != 0)
        {
          tempVar % 10;
           tempVar /= 10;
          if ( tempVar % 2 == 0)
          {
              doSomeAction(tempVar);
          }
        }

   }
```

Comment: If I couldn't use the best tools for the job, I'd write a recursive function that grabbed the last digit (`NUM % 10`) and called itself on `NUM / 10`.  Then, on return, multiply the return value by 10, add my own digit if it was even, and return.  This assumes you need the results digits in the same order as the original number.  If not, it's slightly easier.

Comment: This is more of a math question than a C question

Comment: alright I followed you so far. Where I got lost was when you said multiply the return value by 10. Why would we do this? for example say I do Num % 10 where Num=12345, Num%10=5, Num / 10 = 1234.5 I can't do anything to this since we have an odd number. So i'll be back to where I'm started.

Comment: In the case of 246, what will you return?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the need to use recursion here, it only complicates stuff -feels good though-, you can use a simple while loop with and if statement:

```
int digit,input,output = 0,currentFactor=1;
//read input
while(input!=0)
{
    digit = input % 10; //read digit
    input = input / 10; //remove digit from input

    if(digit % 2 == 1) //if digit is odd
    {
        output +=  digit*currentFactor; //add digit to output at the position determined by factor
        currentFactor *= 10; //move the position by one digit (multiply factor by 10)
    }
}
return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example if I want to remove all even digits from 123658 and be left with
>   135 how could I do that?
>   ... can't use arrays, character variables or Math.h functions.

OP's code is somewhat close.

`phaseInt = 0;` reminds me of BASIC.  In C, `return` the value instead.

I am sure a non-recursive solution, something like OP's can be written, yet recursion is so tight here.

Pseudo recursion code to not give it all away

```
uint32_t PhaseInt_SansEven(uint32_t n) {
  if (has_a_small_value_that_needs_no_recursion_and_can_return_0(n)) {
    return 0;
  }

  uint32_t msdigits = all_digits_except_the_least(n);
  uint32_t lsdigit = the_least_digit(n);

  // If odd digit
  if (test_for_oddness(lsdigit) {
    // How to "append" the left digits and the 1 right one
    return PhaseInt_SansEven(msdigits) * TBD1 + lsdigit;
  } else {
    // How to "append" the left digits and ""
    return PhaseInt_SansEven(msdigits) + TBD2;
  }
}
```

As [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334083/c-programming-removing-digits-from-an-integer#comment79629190_46334083) commented, an all even digit number needs to return an *empty* number.  Hope 0 is OK.

---

Or non-recursive

```
uint32_t PhaseInt_SansEven(uint32_t n) {
  uint32_t odds = 0;
  uint32_t pow10 = TBD1;  // Think ones place
  while (n) {
    uint32_t least_digit = the_least_digit_think_mod(n);
    n = shift_one_decimal_digit_right_think_divide(n);
    if (least_digit%2) {
      odds += pow10 * least_digit;
      pow10 *= TBD; // Make 10x larger
    }
  }
  return odds;
}
```